# How to autofill city name by giving pin code using javascript and php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pin-code

I am not able to autofill city by giving pincode even though database connection successfull.
Below is the code:
pin.php

```
<body>
<form>
 <label >Pincode </label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Pin Code" name="pin_value" id="pin" maxlength="6"  pattern=".{6,6}" title="Exacty 6 digits"  onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"  onkeypress="set_city()" required="">
<label >City </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter City" name="city_value" id="city" onkeypress="return isCharacterKey(event)" >
<?php

      include("configs.php"); 
      $pin = $_POST['pin'];
      $query = $conn->query("SELECT cityname FROM pincodes WHERE pincode = '$pin'");
      while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
      ?>
        <option> <?php echo $row["cityname"];?></option>
      <?php
      }?>
</form>
<script>
function set_city(){
    var pin = document.getElementById("pin").value;

    $.ajax({
        url: "load_pincode.php",
        method: "post",
        data: {pin: pin},
        success: function(response){
            if(response == ""){
                alert("please enter pincode");
            }
            else{
                $("#city").val(response);
            }
        }

    });
}

</script>
</body>
```

load_pincode.php

```
<?php
    @ob_start();
    session_start();
    include("configs.php");

    $pin = $_POST['pin'];

    if($_POST["pin"]) 
    {
        $uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $user_type = $_SESSION["user_type"];
        if($user_type=="lite"){
            $cur_uid = $uid;

            $uid = $_SESSION["ad_id"];
        }
        $cur_bid = $_SESSION["default_business_id"];
        $q = $conn->query("SELECT user_pin FROM business WHERE year = '$curr_year' AND user_id = '$uid' AND business_id = '$cur_bid'");
        $c;
        while($r=$q->fetch_assoc()){
            $c = $r["user_pin"];
        }
        $qg = $conn->query("SELECT cityname FROM pincodes WHERE pincode = '$pin' ");
        while($rg = $qg->fetch_assoc()) {

            $p = $rg["cityname"];

        } 
    }else{
        echo "prob";
    }
?>
```

Its neither displaying error nor output.I am stuck in this auto-filling not able to move further.
How will I get to know whether it is passing value of pin to load_pincode.php ?

Comment: Are you using your browser console/network tab to check if the request has been made and what the request/response might be?

Comment: As you are not checking for database errors did you look in the php error log?

Comment: Where are you returning something from `load_pincode.php`? You're just getting results but not returning them "to your ajax".

Comment: Where do you set `$curr_year` to a valid value?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and 
 other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Line `$c;` What is that supposed to be doing?

Comment: Code is a mess. Start again

Comment: @kerbholz i am running my code on localhost and using ajax i am returning value to response from load_pincode.php.

Comment: For some reason you send a `pin` then go find the `pin` from `business`, dont check it actually exists, then use the pin you were posted to get city from `pin_codes` There is no logic in this code

Comment: "_i am returning value to response from load_pincode.php_" Well no, you're not

Comment: @RiggsFolly if i add these  "  ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); " Page becomes static

Comment: Static? What do you mean by that? Have you checked your php error logs

Comment: So then how to return that value?

Comment: This question has _two_ answers that tell you how to return your data

Comment: @RiggsFolly its not showing any error. What i meant was page is already autofilled .

Comment: @kerbholz So how will i return the values?

Comment: To quote myself: "_This question has two answers that tell you how to return your data_"

Comment: You don't need to put the select query in the pin.php page . Secondly in the load_pin.php page echo the city name properly , you will get the results .

Answer (score 0):

You need to return json array of the result and modify the ajax script to display the city. Please see below.

```
load_pincode.php

<?php
        @ob_start();
        session_start();
        include("configs.php");

        $pin = $_POST['pin'];

        if($_POST["pin"]) 
        {
            $uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $user_type = $_SESSION["user_type"];
            if($user_type=="lite"){
                $cur_uid = $uid;

                $uid = $_SESSION["ad_id"];
            }
            $cur_bid = $_SESSION["default_business_id"];
            $q = $conn->query("SELECT user_pin FROM business WHERE year = '$curr_year' AND user_id = '$uid' AND business_id = '$cur_bid'");
            $c;
            while($r=$q->fetch_assoc()){
                $c = $r["user_pin"];
            }
            $qg = $conn->query("SELECT cityname FROM pincodes WHERE pincode = '$pin' ");
            while($rg = $qg->fetch_assoc()) {

                $p = $rg["cityname"];

            } 

            echo json_encode(array('city' => $p)); exit();
        }else{
            echo "prob";
        }
?>

-------------------------------------------------
$.ajax({
    url: "load_pincode.php",
    method: "post",
    data: {pin: pin},
    success: function(response){
        if(response == ""){
            alert("please enter pincode");
        }
        else{
            $("#city").val(response.city);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you. I did the changes then to i am not getting output.

Comment: Could you please check the response value? Are you getting city there?

Comment: I am not getting any value

Answer (score 0):

I am not going through your whole code but 
First of all you are getting the value of city name according to the pincode but not returning it ,

```
  $qg = $conn->query("SELECT cityname FROM pincodes WHERE pincode = '$pin' ");
      while($rg = $qg->fetch_assoc()) {

        $p = $rg["cityname"];

     } 
   echo json_encode($p); // here getting the city name
```